# ParserError: Expected identifier but got 'public'

Tags: solidity

ParserError: Expected identifier but got 'public', I am new to solidity using remix to compile also tried different version.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0
pragma solidity >=0.4.22 <0.9.0;
struct list{
    string Pan;
    uint age;
    address Address;
    bool Enrolled;
    bool voted;
} 
struct candidate_list{
    string Name;
    address Address;
    uint id;
    bool listed;
}
address election_officer;
string public decimal="0";// getting error here
uint public totalSupply;
address public founder;
```

Answer (score 2):

take a look at the [Structure of a Contract](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.14/structure-of-a-contract.html) in the doc

you are missing the contract part, check the following code:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0
pragma solidity >=0.4.22 <0.9.0;

contract ContractName {
  struct list {
    string Pan;
    uint256 age;
    address Address;
    bool Enrolled;
    bool voted;
  }
  struct candidate_list {
    string Name;
    address Address;
    uint256 id;
    bool listed;
  }
  address election_officer;
  string public decimal = '0'; // getting error here
  uint256 public totalSupply;
  address public founder;
}
```